# JOptionaPane Inputdialogbox and buttons

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

The below code is working perfecly

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Input", 
           "Dialog title",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

Now I have Ok and Cancel buttons. I want to do something like

```
if(OK is selected){
String input1 = input
do something with input1
}
else if (cancel is selected){
System.dispose();
}
```

I'm clueless about what to write inside if condition. I know that for ShowOptionDialog I can get an int of selected option and use it but for inputdialog Im not sure how I can get both the selected option and input text.

Could you please help me

Answer (score 3):

So the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) say

> Returns:
>   user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

That mean that something like

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Input", 
       "Dialog title",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
if (input != null) {
    // User accepted
} else {
    // User cancelled
}
```

Should work...

Comment: I just tried and when I click "Cancel", it's throwing NullPointerException. Bot "OK" is working fine.

Comment: What are you doing with `input` after the use presses `Cancel`?  The Docs clear state that it's `null`.

Comment: For the purpose of my program, it works fine. I can use the input for my business logic. But was just curious about "Cancel" option. What if user clicks cancel, the program need to execute some abc logic. Is it possible to do?

Comment: If they click `Cancel`, then you get `null` value returned, if you get a `null` value, then you need to assign a default (I'm guessing based on your comments)...so, yes, of course it's possible